Overleaf: al compilar las el color shading se sale de las figuras
estoy trabajando en un documento en Latex en el que estoy dibujando lo siguiente:

Como ven se genera un recuadro del color de la figura más grande y así pasa con las demás.
¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? Al parecer solo pasa cuando uso esta configuración de degrado con left color, middle color y right color.
Este es el código:
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}

            \draw coordinate (A) at (0,1);
            \draw coordinate (B) at (0,-0.75);
            \draw coordinate (C) at (5.6,1);
            \draw coordinate (D) at (5.6,-0.75);

            \draw [left color=cyan!50!blue!25, 
        right color=cyan!50!blue!25, 
        middle color=cyan!50!blue!10,draw=none] (0,1) -- (1,0.75) -- (1,1.5) -- (2,1.5) arc(180:0:0.8) -- (4.6,1.5) -- (4.6,0.75) -- (D|-C) -- (D) -- (4.6,-0.5) -- (4.6,-1.25) -- (1,-1.25) -- (1,-0.5) -- (A |- B);

        \draw [line width=1.5pt,draw=cyan] (0,1) -- (1,0.75) -- (1,1.5) -- (2,1.5) arc(180:0:0.8) -- (4.6,1.5) -- (4.6,0.75) -- (D|-C);

        \draw [line width=1.5pt,draw=cyan] (5.6,-0.75) -- (4.6,-0.5) -- (4.6,-1.25) -- (1,-1.25) -- (1,-0.5) -- (0,-0.75);

        \draw [draw=purple,-stealth,line width=1.5pt,rounded corners =20pt] (-0.5,-2) -- (-0.5,0) -- (0.5,0);

        \draw [draw=purple,-stealth,line width=1.5pt,rounded corners =20pt] (5.25,0) -- (6.25,0) -- (6.25,-2);

        \draw [draw=ForestGreen,rounded corners,line width=1.5pt,left color=ForestGreen!50!OliveGreen!25, 
        right color=OliveGreen!50!OliveGreen!25, 
        middle color=ForestGreen!50!OliveGreen!10] (-1.5,-3) rectangle ++ (2,1) node [pos=.5] {\textcolor{ForestGreen}{\textit{Dominio}}};

        \draw [draw=RoyalPurple,rounded corners,line width=1.5pt,left color=RoyalPurple!50!Orchid!25, 
        right color=Orchid!50!Orchid!25, 
        middle color=RoyalPurple!50!Orchid!10] (5.25,-3) rectangle ++ (2,1) node [pos=.5] {\textcolor{RoyalPurple}{\textit{Rango}}};

        \draw node at (2.75,0.25) {\textcolor{cyan}{$f(x) = 2x$}};

        \draw [draw=BlueGreen,line width=1pt](-1,-1.5) circle (8pt) node {\textcolor{BlueGreen}{$7$}};

        \draw [draw=YellowOrange,line width=1pt](-1,-0.6) circle (8pt) node {\textcolor{YellowOrange}{$5$}};

        \draw [draw=BlueViolet,line width=1pt](-0.5,0.25) circle (8pt) node {\textcolor{BlueViolet}{$2$}};

         \draw [draw=BlueViolet,line width=1pt](6.25,0.25) circle (8pt) node {\textcolor{BlueViolet}{$4$}};

        \draw [draw=YellowOrange,line width=1pt](6.75,-0.6) circle (8pt) node {\textcolor{YellowOrange}{$10$}};

        \draw [draw=BlueGreen,line width=1pt](6.75,-1.5) circle (8pt) node {\textcolor{BlueGreen}{$14$}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
            
\end{document}

Gracias!
